# Accessing Parent node in Child in ANTLR 4.4

Tags: java, antlr

Am new to ANTLR framework. I am working with parsing a Java file. Using ANTLR I am generating the `JavaLexer, JavaParser, JavaListener, JavaBaseListener` uning org.antlr.v4.Tool
Here I have an issue. I create a class that overrides the required methods of `JavaBaseListener`

Here is the code:

JavaMetaDataReader.java

```
public class JavaMetaDataReader  extends JavaBaseListener{


    @Override
    public void enterAnnotation(AnnotationContext ctx) 
    {
        System.out.println(ctx.getText());
    }

    @Override
    public void enterAnnotationName(AnnotationNameContext ctx)
    {
        System.out.println(ctx.getText());


    }

    @Override
    public void enterElementValuePairs(ElementValuePairsContext ctx)
    { 
        System.out.println(ctx.getText());
        System.out.println("Parent: "+ctx.getParent().getText());
    }

}
```

JavaReader.Java   //Contains the main method.

```
public class JavaReader {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        File fileTobeRead = new File("./src/main/java/sample/HelloWord.java");
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;
        try {
            fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(fileTobeRead);

            ANTLRInputStream input = new ANTLRInputStream(fileInputStream);
            JavaLexer lexer = new JavaLexer(input);
            CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
            JavaParser parser = new JavaParser(tokens);
            ParseTree tree = parser.compilationUnit(); // parse

            ParseTreeWalker walker = new ParseTreeWalker(); // create standard walker

            JavaMetaDataReader javaMetaDataReader = new JavaMetaDataReader();
            walker.walk(javaMetaDataReader, tree); // initiate walk of tree with listener

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

HelloWorld.java

```
public class HelloWord {

    @SuppressWarnings(value = "Helloo")
    private void helloWorld() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Here HelloWorld.java is the file that needs to be parsed.
Here am trying to access the annotations.

The `enterAnnotation` prints: `@SuppressWarnings(value="Helloo")`

The `enterAnnotationName` prints: `SuppressWarnings`

The first statement in `enterElementValuePair` prints: `value="Helloo"`

The second statement in `enterElementValuePair` prints: `Parent: @SuppressWarnings(value="Helloo")`

But i need it to print `SuppressWarnings` (the valure printed by `enterAnnotationName`
I don't know where I went wrong. I need to access the annotationName inside enterElementValuePairs.
What should I do?

Kindly help me as I am a beginner.

Comment: Use  `ParseTreeWalker walker = ParseTreeWalker.DEFAULT`.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't include a copy of the grammar, so I can only guess about the relation between your rules. It seems the parent of `elementValuePairs` is `annotation`, *not* `annotationName`. You need to first access the parent (`AnnotationContext`), and then call `AnnotationContext.annotationName()` to get the previous sibling of the `ElementValuePairsContext`.

If you are using the [unofficial "optimized" release](https://github.com/tunnelvisionlabs/antlr4cs/releases) of the Java target, you can add the following annotation to your `enterElementValuePairs` method to ensure that a compiler error is reported if you later use the `elementValuePairs` rule in a way which would break this. Note that this requires the `@version{}` action to be used when the grammar is modified, as described in the link below.

```
@RuleDependencies({
  @RuleDependency(recognizer=JavaParser.class, rule=JavaParser.RULE_elementValuePairs,
                  version=0, dependents={Dependents.PARENTS, Dependents.DESCENDANTS}),
  @RuleDependency(recognizer=JavaParser.class, rule=JavaParser.RULE_annotation,
                  version=0, dependents=Dependents.SELF),
  @RuleDependency(recognizer=JavaParser.class, rule=JavaParser.RULE_annotationName,
                  version=0, dependents=Dependents.DESCENDANTS)
})
```

More information about using rule dependencies is available here:
https://github.com/sharwell/antlr4/wiki/Rule-Versioning